# How to get number from a string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a string like this `'sdf,11-df,12-asd,sadfsdf'`. But I need only numbers from this string in multiple rows like this.

1. 11
2. 12

I need numbers between (,) and (-) that's the actual requirement. String can be like 'sd47f,11-df,12-asd,sadfsdf,12-ds,32-fsdfsd' anything, But numbers will always between (,) and (-)

or find numbers between (,) and  (-) it will also help me.

Thanks in advance.
I need any solution guys please help,

Comment: A solution would be to use a stored function to parse the value.

Comment: can you help me how? @virustrinity

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
 DECLARE @data nvarchar(max) = 'sdf,11-df,12-asd,sadfsdf'
  select substring(@data,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@data),2)
  union all
  select substring(@data,PATINDEX('%[-]%',REVERSE(@data))-1,2)
```

**Update**

> You can also use a function which returns as a table

```
  CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric (@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN ( select   LEFT(value,2) as Value from
string_split(@strAlphaNumeric,',')  where PATINDEX('%[0-9]-%',value)
> 0 )

 END GO

 SELECT * from
 dbo.udf_GetNumeric('sd47f,11-df,12-asd,sadfsdf,12-ds,32-fsdfsd')
```

Comment: Thanks, @plaidDK you made my day.

Comment: But It is not working in other string format like  'sdf,11-df,12-asd,13-sadfsdf'

Comment: Did you try `sd47f,11-df,12-asd,sadfsdf`?

Comment: I need integer between (,) and (-) that's the actual requirement. 
String can be like 'sd47f,11-df,12-asd,sadfsdf,12-ds,32-fsdfsd' but numbers will always between  (,) and (-)

Comment: @sachinjoshi Ahh okay,my bad i will change it.

Comment: @plaidDK Thank you for your support.

Comment: @sachinjoshi updated my question to use a function. Remember to mark MatSnow answer as correct so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 3):

Following will work with SQL Server 2016 or higher:

```
DECLARE @str varchar(50) = 'sd47f,11-df,12-asd,sadfsdf,12-ds,32-fsdfsd'

SELECT
LEFT(Value, CHARINDEX('-', Value)-1)
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@str, ',')
WHERE PATINDEX('%[0-9]-%',Value) > 0
```

Comment: Thank You @MatSnow it is working perfectly working for me

Comment: damn it - you were fast than me - Was just going to do it :)

Comment: @plaidDK Sorry ;-)